# Splash screen is Blank when sleeping

Tags: java, android, sleep, wait, splash-screen

I am trying to get the splash layout to appear for 5 seconds and then to switch over to the mainmenu layout.  The screen is blank for about 5 seconds, and then the mainmenu layout pops up.  If I just run the splash layout without sleeping, it runs just fine, so I do not think that is the problem. Any ideas?

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mainMenu();
    }




    private void mainMenu()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

    }
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309659/android-the-splash-screen-does-not-get-shown-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beacause u are doing Thread.sleep on Main UI thread.. Thats not recommended..

Use Timer instead, Use below code..

```
private Timer timer;
private Handler handler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    handler = new Handler();

        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    YourActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
                }
            });

        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000);
}
```